when i am creating 'create-extra-metas' using cli i am getting 'invalid program argument' Error
    ../../target/debug/spl-transfer-hook create-extra-metas HooGStFZgkeZ5wCSg9vHtuEYBSotB26tVEvXra4PEKYJ MoxLrhGXAjVnEiVAjG5ycQbp9MVd4sjfj1yLPFVXhkh

error: send transaction: error: send transaction: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: invalid program argument; 7 log messages:
  Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]

  Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success

  Program HooGStFZgkeZ5wCSg9vHtuEYBSotB26tVEvXra4PEKYJ invoke [1]

  Program log: Instruction: InitializeExtraAccountMetaList

  Program log: Error: InvalidArgument

  Program HooGStFZgkeZ5wCSg9vHtuEYBSotB26tVEvXra4PEKYJ consumed 1107 of 399850 compute 
   units

  Program HooGStFZgkeZ5wCSg9vHtuEYBSotB26tVEvXra4PEKYJ failed: invalid program argument

I am getting above on initializing the extra metas account in Transfer hook.
upon logging i can see that extra-metas-account are empty ?
    ./spl-transfer-hook create-extra-metas 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh MoxLrhGXAjVnEiVAjG5ycQbp9MVd4sjfj1yLPFVXhkh  


error: send transaction: error: send transaction: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: invalid program argument; 13 log messages:

  Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]

  Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success

  Program 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh invoke [1]

  Program log: Program ID: 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh

  Program log: Accounts: [AccountInfo { key: HmFbb2nE598yVXuqQgMksUh8bCPLsYDKTwMaCnKV4aLo, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: false, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 1002240, data.len: 0, .. }, AccountInfo { key: MoxLrhGXAjVnEiVAjG5ycQbp9MVd4sjfj1yLPFVXhkh, owner: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 2519520, data.len: 234, data: 01000000e7f5421d9cc0c0f0a39442d8103b74e603d422017cde454262af5191b2003cb000e40b54020000000901000000000000000000000000000000000000, .. }, AccountInfo { key: GcU5ykU5RFcEVQtumtqBYZ7tKNnxeZZBFg53P15mywvP, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: true, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 68015651504, data.len: 0, .. }, AccountInfo { key: 11111111111111111111111111111111, owner: NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: true, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 1, data.len: 14, data: 73797374656d5f70726f6772616d, .. }]

  Program log: Extra Account Metas: []

  Program log: Instruction: InitializeExtraAccountMetaList

  Program log: program_id:
 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh
  Program log: Accounts: [AccountInfo { key: HmFbb2nE598yVXuqQgMksUh8bCPLsYDKTwMaCnKV4aLo, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: false, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 1002240, data.len: 0, .. }, AccountInfo { key: MoxLrhGXAjVnEiVAjG5ycQbp9MVd4sjfj1yLPFVXhkh, owner: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 2519520, data.len: 234, data: 01000000e7f5421d9cc0c0f0a39442d8103b74e603d422017cde454262af5191b2003cb000e40b54020000000901000000000000000000000000000000000000, .. }, AccountInfo { key: GcU5ykU5RFcEVQtumtqBYZ7tKNnxeZZBFg53P15mywvP, owner: 11111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: true, is_writable: true, executable: false, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 68015651504, data.len: 0, .. }, AccountInfo { key: 11111111111111111111111111111111, owner: NativeLoader1111111111111111111111111111111, is_signer: false, is_writable: false, executable: true, rent_epoch: 18446744073709551615, lamports: 1, data.len: 14, data: 73797374656d5f70726f6772616d, .. }]
  Program log: extra_account_metas: []
  Program log: Error: InvalidArgument
  Program 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh consumed 216628 of 399850 compute units
  Program 3MsUqMDPiDqNbJihXdfyhqauJ6gXEE6Rrb1wjdUtD4Fh failed: invalid program argument


Note your message is 'invalid program argument' not 'invalid program'. Ie you're trying to call HooGStFZgkeZ5wCSg9vHtuEYBSotB26tVEvXra4PEKYJ with an argument it doesn't expect.
Can you please paste the contents of the screenshot as actual text? That way other people that have the same error can find this question.

@mikemaccana texted version is edit , In logs i can see that cli is not passing extra meta accounts , the array is empty
